# List of Tosafists or Geonim?

Tags: history, tosfot, geonim

I went through a list of Master Profiles of my ancestors on Geni.com and I saw many profiles which said "tosafist" in their title or description, as well as many which said "Gaon of Sura" or "Gaon of Pumpeditha", etc., but none of them were in the existing Geni.com projects for "Tosafists" or "Geonim". Is there a sefer which quotes a list of tosafists or geonim, or some resources which has a big list of them so that I can go through it and add them to the Geni.com projects?

Comment: There is a sefer by אפרים א. אורבך called בעלי התוספות which is one of the most comprehensive works on the Tosafists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as far as the Gaonim the sefer סדר הדורות הקצר pp.123-133 provides an extensive list of all the Gaonim of the period differentiating between those who hailed from Pumbedisa and those from Sura. From p.133 - 135 it list the important seforim that were written during this period.

It lists the following (Everyone please feel free to edit if I haven't Anglicised them correctly):

### **Gaonei Pumbedisa**

1. Rav Chanan M'ashikya
2. Rav Mari son of Rav Dimi
3. Rav Chanina from Bei Gihera
4. Rav Chana
5. Rav Ra'ava
6. Rav Bustenai
7. Rav Huna Mari son of Yosef
8. Rav Chiya M'misha
9. Rav Ravya Moronai
10. Rav Natronai son of Rav Nechemya
11. Rav Yehuda
12. Rav Yosef Kusnai
13. Rav Shmuel son of Rav Mar
14. Rav Natronai Kahana son of Rav Amona
15. Rav Achai M'Shabcha
16. Rav Avraham Kahana
17. Rav Dudai son of Mar Nachman
18. Rav Chananya son of Rav M'sharshya
19. Rav Milca son of Rav Acha
20. Rav Rava son of Rav Dudai
21. Rav Shinui Gaon
22. Rav Chaninai Kahana son of Rav Avraham
23. Rav Huna HaLevi son of Rav Yitzchak Gaon
24. Rav Menashe son of Rav Yosef
25. Rav Yeshaya HaLevi son of Mar Aba
26. Rav Yosef son of Rav Sheila M'Shilhi
27. Rav Kahana son of Rav Chaninai
28. Rav Ivumai son of Rav Avraham
29. Rav Yosef son of Rav Aba
30. Rav Avraham son of Rav Sherira
31. Rav Yosef son of Rav Chiya
32. Rav Yitzchak son Rav Chananya (Hunai)
33. Rav Yosef son of Rav Ravi
34. Rav Paltoi son of Rav Abaye
35. Rav Acha (Achai) Kahana son of Mar Rav
36. Rav Menachem son of Rav Yosef son of Chiya
37. Rav Matisyahu son of Mar Rabi
38. Rav Rabbah son Rav Ami
39. Rav Tzemach son of Rav Paltoi
40. Rav Hai son of Dovid
41. Rav Kimoi son of Rav Acha
42. Rav Yehuda son of Rav Shmuel
43. Rav Kohen Tzedek son of Rav Yosef
44. Rav Mivsar Kahan son of Rav Kimoi
45. Rebbi Kalonimus son of Moshe
46. Rebbi Shabsai son of Avraham Donollo
47. Rav Tzemach son of Rav Kafnai
48. Rav Chanina son of Rav Yehuda
49. Rav Aharon son of Rav Yosef Gaon
50. Rav Sherirah Gaon son of Chananya
51. Rav Hai Gaon (From the scholars of Bavel)
52. Rav Meshulam HaGadol the son of Kalonimus
53. Rabbi yaakov son of Nissim
54. Rav Chadai son of Yitzchak - Ibn Shprut
55. Rebbi Menachem son of Yaakov - Ben Seruk
56. Rebbi Shmarya son of Elchonon
57. Rebbi Chushiel son of Elchonon

### **Gaonei Sura**

1. Rav Mar son of Rav Huna
2. Rav Chanina
3. Rav Huna
4. Rav Sheshna
5. Rav Chanina Minahar Pekod
6. Rav Hilai HaLevi Megareish
7. Rav Yaakov HaKohen Minahar Pekod
8. Rav Mar the son of Shmuel
9. Rav Mari Kohen Minahar Pekod
10. Rav Acha Rabbah
11. Rav Yehudai son of Rav Nachman Gaon
12. Rav Achonai Kahan son of Rav Pappa
13. Rav Chaninai Kahana son of Rav Huna
14. Rav Mar HaLevi son of Rav Mesharshya
15. Rav Bivui HaLevi son of Mar Rava Minahar Pekod
16. Rav Hilai son of Rav mari
17. Rav Yaakov HaKohen son of Rav Mordechai
18. Rav Tzadok son of Mar Ashi
19. Rav Hilai son of Rav Chanina
20. Rav Kimoi son of Rav Ashi
21. Rav Moshe Kahana son of Rav Yaakov
22. Rav Kohen Tzedek son of Rav Aivomai
23. Rav Shimon Kiyera
24. Rav Sar Shalom son of Rav Boaz
25. Rav Natronai son of Rav Hilai
26. Rav Amram Gaon son of Rav Sheshna
27. Rav Nachshon son of Rav Tzadok
28. Rav Tzemach son of Rav Chayim
29. Rav Milca
30. Rav Hai son of Rav Nachshon
31. Rav Hilai son of Rav Natronai
32. Rav Shalom son of Rav Mishael
33. Rav Yaakov son of Rav Natronai
34. Rav Yom Tov Kahana son of Rav Yaakov
35. Rav Sa'adiya Gaon
36. Rav Yosef son of Yaakov
37. Rebbi Aharon son of Moshe son Ben Meir

Please find below photos of the relevant pages which provides more information about each one of the Gaonim:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So just checking, this is the whole list? What about the yeshivos of Tyre and Ramla?

Comment: This is the list as cited in the sefer seder hadoros hakotzair - it only lists those from Sura and Pumbedisa from what I can see. I hope that helps!

Comment: Do you know if there is a Seder hadoros ha'aruch?

Comment: Sure, the Seder Hadoros was written by Rav Yechiel Halperin in the seventeenth century and writes from Adam HaRishon until his time - https://seforimcenter.com/Seder-HaDorot-HaShalem--Rabbi-Yehiel-Ben-Shlomo-Heilprin-2-vol.---Yarid-HaSfarim-Ed.__p-10397.aspx. Personally I prefer the seder hadoros hakotzair by Rav Shlomo Benizri as it is more modern and therefore continues the history up until the gedolim of our time.

Answer (score 1):

[THe Rishonim](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=Awr9GjEcXDZfPzsAfplXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTByb2lvbXVuBGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzcg--/RV=2/RE=1597426845/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FRishonim-Biographical-prominent-ArtScroll-Judaiscope%2Fdp%2F0899064523/RK=2/RS=etOTQSBoKQ2NUQxwXSow._jB9Kg-) by Hersh Goldwurm is a good source for many of the Tosafists.

Answer (score 1):

So as far as the Baalei Tosafos, I since noticed a small paragraph also in the Seder Hadoros HaKotzair p.165 where it lists some 15 names (which I have itemised) as well as some accompanying background information.

[image]